# Laravel whereInStrict for Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to utilise the usage of `whereIn` method for the query builder but with a different logic from the default one. I am trying to fetch users that have relationship models with whereIn but strictly, meaning if only the one's from the array that I am passing should be fetched.

Example:

```
User::whereHas('tags', function($subQuery) use ($tags){
      $subQuery->whereIn('tag_id', $tags);
});
```

`$tags` is an array containing `[1,2,3]` and there is table called user_tags that has multiple tags for each of the users.

If User1 has `[1,2,4]` then it shouldn't be fetched from this query and I only want to fetch it if he has `[1,2,3]` but whereIn will return it anyway because the occurence of `1` and `2` in the array makes the query to return it.

There is whereInStrict method but it is only for the Collection class so I can't really utilise it.

What are some ways to accomplish this?

Comment: if you pass `[1, 2, 3]` you only want users having only `[1, 2, 3]` or having at least `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @lagbox having at least `[1,2,3]` meaning that can have `[1,2,3,5,7,9]`.

Answer (score 4):

The `whereHas` method takes more arguments. It also takes an operator and a count:

```
whereHas('tags', function (...) { ... }, '=', count($tags))
```

By default this is `>=, 1`. So we are adjusting this to say you want all users who have all these tags (by count), not just some of them.